# Get database ID from ListView

Tags: java, android

I get data from database (id, name) and I want to display (name) in a ListView. When user clicks I need to get database (id) to perform an action. I get it working but my solution seems complex for such a simple thing. I would like somehow to store (id) in the ListView in a hidden way and beeing able to retrieve it when item is selected by user.
Here is my solution:

```
class Route { //structure to store the data in ListView
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Route (int Id, String Name) {
        id = Id;
        name = Name;
    }
}

// Create a custom adapter, we also created a corresponding
// layout (route_row) for each item of the ListView
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Route> {
      private final Context context;
      private final String[] values;

      public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Route> routes) {
        super(context, R.layout.route_row, routes);
        this.context = context;
        //Get the list of string array to display in the ListView
        String[] values = new String[routes.size()];
        //Loop around all the items to get the list of values to be displayed
        for (int i=0; i<routes.size(); i++) values[i] =  
                  routes.get(i).id + " - " + routes.get(i).name;
        //We added route.id to route.name for debugging but route.id is not necessary
        this.values = values; //String array used to display data in the ListView
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.route_row, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.routeName);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        return rowView;
      }
    } 

//output is a JSON array composed of JSON object routes 
void DisplayListView(String output) { (id, name)
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayList<Route> list = new ArrayList<Route>();

    //Convert the JSON to ArrayList<Route>
    try {
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(output); //Get JSON array
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    int id;
    String name;
    for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++) {
        jsonObj = json.getJSONObject(i); //Get each JSON object
        id = jsonObj.getInt("Id");
        name = jsonObj.getString("Name");
        list.add( new Route(id, name));
    }
    }
     catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.w("Commute", ex.toString());
         ex.printStackTrace();
     } 

    //Create ArrayAdapter
    MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
                                                                    list);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

    //Set a listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
              "Click ListItem Number " +
                          ((Route)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).id,
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
              .show();
            //It works when user clicks we display route.id 
          }
        }); 
    }
```

Is there not a simpler way to do this ? I found similar questions but no simple or clear answer.
Can I avoid the custom adapter ? I just want to display a simple ListView with a text for each line.
Can I avoid to loop around the ArrayAdapter to create the String array for the adpater ? That seems really an unefficient way to do.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it's a best practice, but you can actually store that `id` in a hidden `TextView` or label and just set the `android:visibility="gone"` for that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will elaborate the answer later but here are some part of the answer.

- Creating a ListActivity is a better way to start (will take care of registering the listener for item click)
- In the custom array adapter, override: `public long getItemId (int position)` to return the appropriate id when `onListItemClick` get called.
- When using SimpleCursorAdapter it seems the database id will be automatically identified by `onListItemClick`. This is maybe because we provided id when doing the binding of the SimpleCursorAdapter:
  `new String[] { "Name", "IsOffer", "Distance", BaseColumns._ID }, //Columns from table BaseColumns._ID
   new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.isOffer, R.id.distance, R.id.id },`

Answer (score 0):

Use the setTag() method of View to attach your own object to the view. Then you can use something like this:

```
        vh.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ForumThread th = (((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).thread);
            th.setWatched(!th.isWatched());
            th.saveLater();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```